# Avoid memory re-allocation in tensorflow while_loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory

In every step of the while_loop, I want to update a 0.5 GB variable. I cannot avoid the loop because each iteration depends on the previous iteration. My program need to run the while loop for 100 million times.

To test the performance of `tf.while` in this scenario, I make a test. The update here is simply adding a constant to the variable.

However, even this simple loop takes 24 seconds and requires 4 times 1 GB memory. I suspect the loop is constantly trying to reallocate 1 GB chunks of memory, which is horribly slow on a GPU. The GPU has 4 GB memory, when I set the variable to 2 GB, I get oom.

Is it possible to avoid the re-allocation?

I can use `x` as a loop variable instead of using the `tf.control_dependencies`. But that uses a bit more memory.

`tf.contrib.compiler.jit.experimental_jit_scope` leads to oom.

Thanks.

Test:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from functools import partial
from timeit import default_timer as timer

def body1(x, i):
    a = tf.assign(x, x + 0.001)
    with tf.control_dependencies([a]):
        return i + 1


def make_loop1(x, end_ix):
    i = tf.Variable(0, name="i", dtype=np.int32)
    cond = lambda i2: tf.less(i2, end_ix)
    body = partial(body1, x)
    return tf.while_loop(
        cond, body, [i], back_prop=False,
        parallel_iterations=1)


def main():
    N = int(1e9 / 4)
    x = tf.get_variable('x', shape=N, dtype=np.float32,
                        initializer=tf.ones_initializer)

    end_ix = tf.constant(int(1000), dtype=np.int32)
    loop1 = make_loop1(x, end_ix)

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init_op)
        print("running_loop1")
        st = timer()
        sess.run(loop1)
        en = timer()
        print(st - en)
        print(sess.run(x[0]))

main()
```

Comment: You could try using `tf.assign_add` instead of `tf.assign`.

Comment: `tf.assign_add(x, x)` makes it to 12 second. still horribly slow.

Comment: How about the memory usage? Have you tried to add a constant tensor rather than a variable?

Comment: If tensorflow re-allocates memory in every evaluation of an op, performance will suck. In my actual use case, the update changes over time.

Comment: I think `tf.assign_add` has avoided memory reallocation. I tried to run the same loop in native `numpy` and it is around 30% faster than TF. TF's performance does not seem to be as bad as you might expect.